# C++ Iterators Issue

Tags: c++, xcode, iterator

So I spent a solid 30 minutes trying to get a working iterator for a list wondering what exactly I was doing wrong but now I can say Im genuinely baffled unless its an xcode issue. I initially tried creating an iterator (listIterator) and xcode would return the error "Expected '(' for function style-cast or type construction". However, after getting tired of trying I copy and pasted a line I found elsewhere on Stack to initialize the iterator, which thankfully works perfectly. My problem is that both lines are identical yet only one is raising an error[image: identical iterator inits with different results]

Could someone explain to me why xcode is only recognizing is raising an error for only the second one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a variable called `list`. So the `list` in the line with the error is referring to that variable. I'm assuming that you've done something like `using namespace std;` - this is one example of why exactly you should never do that. Then you could have:

```
 std::list<int> myIntList;
 std::list<int>::iterator myIntListIterator;

 std::list<int> list;
 std::list<int>::iterator listIterator;
```

However, in a real program, I don't think just `list` would ever be an appropriate variable name because it denotes type rather than use.

Comment: Ahh, that would make plenty of sense! Well I should probably heed the warning and start typing out my std::'s

Comment: @sonobenissimo you don't necessarily have to start with typing out std:: for everything, it would suffice the wrint 'using std::cout' etc. for the stuff that you specifically need.